# BATch one line cmd: Replace filename doesnt work?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to replace an file name but it doesnt work.

I know that this works: (command line, no .bat file!)

```
SET G="test string"
echo %G:s=a%
```

But if i use a for loop it doesnt work. Why? (command line, no .bat file!)

```
for /r . %G in (*.jpg) do echo %G:s=a%
```

Thanks for help in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing a *Batch variable* with a FOR command *replaceable parameter*. In these lines:

```
SET G="test string"
echo %G:s=a%
```

The `G` is a Batch variable, but in this one:

```
for /r . %G in (*.jpg) do echo %G:s=a%
```

The `G` is a FOR replaceable parameter and the substring replacement only works on Batch variables. The solution is to assign the FOR parameter into a Batch variable and then do the replacement. However, the only way to do so is via *delayed expansion*, so the solution is this:

```
cmd /V:ON /C for /r . %G in (*.jpg) do @set "G=%G" ^& echo !G:s=a!
```

For further details, search this site for "delayed expansion" or type `cmd /?` and `set /?`, and carefully read "delayed expansion" references.

Answer (score 1):

A for loop in a BAT needs to double the "%%".
Also, the for variable doesn't support substitutions, and variables get substituted before executed.

For /r . %%G in (*.jpg) do @echo %%G

Try this:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%g in (*.JPG) do @set Q=%%g && echo !Q:t=X!
```